# How to list members from an GraphQL's Enum type with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

I have a GraphQL mutation that accepts an Enum as one of the inputs, I would like to list those enum's members as a select on the UI. How should I do that? Do I need to hard code the members to the select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `__type` field to get an enum type's values. For example, you could ask for the values of a `Color` enum:

```
{
   __type(name: "Color") {
     enumValues {
       name 
     }
   }
}
```

And it might return a response like:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "__type" : {
      "enumValues" : [
        { "name" : "WHITE" },
        { "name" : "BLUE" },
        { "name" : "BLACK" },
        { "name" : "RED" },
        { "name" : "GREEN" },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you could use that response to render the UI.

More info about GraphQL Introspection: http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/

Comment: could you please let me know how could i use this response to render in select tag, as i am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property '__type' of undefined" while trying to use the data.__type (obtained from __type query) in select tag of ""useMutation" hook?